# Identifying/operating an automatic watering system

Tags: tools, sprinkler-system

I recently bought a house built circa 1970 in France, and it came with an automatic watering system (date of setup unknown, so any time between then and now), controlled by this:

[image]

I've been unable to find any kind of instructions on how to operate the triple cogs systems on the web, searching for "flash" or "flask" (whatever that brand is) doesn't yield anything.

Would anyone know (ideally) what's this model so that I can find instructions, or at least have an idea on how to operate the cogs?

Comment: Great question! It is probably a model from the 70s and still functional! I would say adjust the wheels, and plug in your pump in the plug opening.

Comment: Actually, the water is flowing, I'm just having a hard time understanding what the wheels do on the "automation" part. But I investigated a bit, and from what I understand, the orange and black arrows on the cogs hit the 3 black plastic bits at the top, rotating small cogs inside, making the circuits go on and off. I'm still far from understanding everything though ^^ 
For now, I'll keep using the manual mode (two switches that one barely see on the bottom of the photo)

Comment: Do the purplish pins on the dial pull out?

Comment: A picture of just the dial from straight on would help.

Comment: Might consider posting in diy SE if no answer here.

Comment: They don't pull out, but they rotate. They can be rotated manually, or when hit by the black and oranges arrow on the cogs. I think I start understanding the thing though after playing with it more, it's just not 100% clear yet. I'll snap a good quality picture this evening  (aka 12 hours frow now :-D )

Comment: Googling timer RM 120 H RES 9123 gives some results e.g. https://www.nederland-marktplaats.nl/doe-het-zelf-en-verbouw/elektra-en-kabels/flash-multi-res-9123-timer-rm-120h-16a-250v_i258777 - since there is no picture I am not sure though

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking for flash coupure arro?
I can't see the rest of the word.
The triple cogs are the timer, I'm thinking you know that.
I would set the 2 bottom cogs on 0 and the top for for 6 on the puple peg on the 6 which is close to where it is.
I get the feeling the switch on the left is set to off and might operate the timer the switch at the right looks like its on. If it comes on you can figure out the timer and set it to the time you want.
That system is an old man but if you get the name on the bottom I might be able to find something?. The round hole next to the switch I believe is off.
I also think something may be missing? The 3 timers could be different zones?
Thats where I would start. You might fair better getting a newer control

[image]
The the 2 red pointers per dial are the current time, there are 3 red pointers and 3 gray pointers I would set the grey pointers on the time you want the sprinklers to come on.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could replace it with a modern unit. I have replaced a couple older units for others, They were fine machines in their day , an intricate collection of gears and cogs, and pin trips with no instructions. Don't remember exactly but a couple very versatile 6 station electronic units were available in US for less than 100 US$